# Why is my non xxxParam field not populated when using @BeanParam

Tags: rest, parameters, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have this test case to demonstrate that I can pass an entity to a resource and when trying to use with @BeanParam input parameter, the type field is never set in my return object.

This is what is sent:

```
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > POST http://localhost:9998/hello
1 > Content-Type: application/json
1 > orgId: xx1
{"orgId":null,"type":"MY-TYPE"}
```

and this is what is sent back:

```
INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 200
1 < Content-Length: 27
1 < Content-Type: application/json
{"orgId":"xx1","type":null}
```

Here is test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class SimpleTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
        rc.property("contextConfig", new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ResourceConfig.class));
        rc.register(SpringLifecycleListener.class);
        rc.registerClasses(HelloResource.class);
        return rc;
    }

    public static class SimpleEntity {
        public String getOrgId() {
            return orgId;
        }

        public void setOrgId(final String orgId) {
            this.orgId = orgId;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(final String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @HeaderParam("orgId")
        private String orgId;
        private String type;
    }

    @Path("hello")
    public static class HelloResource {
        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public SimpleEntity getHello(@BeanParam SimpleEntity entity) {
            return entity;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        SimpleEntity requestEntity= new SimpleEntity();
        requestEntity.setType("MY-TYPE");
        final SimpleEntity entity = target("hello").request().header("orgId", "xx1").post(Entity.entity(requestEntity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), SimpleEntity.class);
        assertNotNull(entity.getOrgId());
        assertNotNull(entity.getType());
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class BlankSpringConfig{}
}
```

Comment: Using BeanParam annotation, value of only those fields which are annotated with  XxxParam annotation can be injected only. See JavaDoc https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html